# Is it possible to query apps for their wallpapers?

Tags: android, android-wallpaper

There are apps that offer their own wallpapers, such as [**Nova Launcher**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher&hl=en), and [**Google's Wallpapers**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.wallpaper):

[image]

[image]

My question is simple:

Is it possible to query such apps for their wallpapers (images and maybe more information) ?

If so, how?

Is there anything special on those apps, that made it possible to find their wallpapers, and choose one to set from there?